# Can `git clean` discover directories that only contain hidden/ignored files

Tags: git, visual-studio

Using git + Visual Studio a lot of times the renaming of folders leaves the folder with the old name in the local repository behind. The reason is that git doesn't track folders and the old folder still contains files like bin/obj/configuation files that are hidden or ignored by git (.gitignore).

`git clean -fdn` doesn't find these folders and `git clean -fdxn` finds all hidden and ignored files which is too much.

What I need is a command that finds folders that only contain ignored/hidden files.